# How to host .net 4.5 with MVC 5 project on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7 32 bit)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-4.5

I am getting issues to deploy/host my MVC 5 project on iis7.5 , Please suggest me steps to host it and getting this type of issue. [image: Please find the image for reference]

Comment: Please refer to this post http://windows2008hosting.asphostportal.com/post/Cheap-ASPNET-MVC-3-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-How-to-Deploy-an-ASPNET-MVC-3-App-to-Web-Hosting-with-5cbin-Deployment.aspx

Comment: checked all the steps mentioned in above link , still not fixed.

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure that you have deployed it properly? Please try to see this post https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28568160/Deploy-MVC-5-Net-web-to-IIS-7-5-Win2008-R2.html

Comment: Thanks , it's done , actually need to update webpages property is true in web.config file.